# F-distibution only depends on degrees of freedom

Tags: self-study, f-distribution

I am reading [ISLP](https://www.statlearning.com/) Chapter 3.2 on multiple linear regressions. They define the F-statistic as $S_1$, the variance of sample 1 from population 1, divided by $S_2$, the variance of sample 2 from population2, each from a different population.

However, the F-statistic only depends on the degrees of freedom of sample 1 and sample 2. My question is: Why doesn't it depend on any other features, such as the sample mean or population mean?

My second question is about plotting the F-distribution. We sample numerators and denominators, but is the sampling done from population 1 and population 2? Or do we sample from all possible populations?
Then again, if population 1 and 2 are fixed, then how come the F-distribution only depends on degree of freedom?

I am not looking for a proof. Just some clarification.

Comment: You are confusing the F-statistic, which is the ratio of the sample variances, which, in turn, depends on the samples, and the *distribution* of the F-statistic under the null hypothesis, which only depends on the degrees of freedom.

Comment: @jbowman, based on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) F-distribution is the $X={\frac {S_{1}/d_{1}}{S_{2}/d_{2}}}$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are random variables of other distributions. but the resulting F-distribution only depends on d1 and d2.

Comment: The F distribution is the distribution of the F-statistic.  Once again you have confused the two.  The F distribution is *not* the $X = (S_1/d_1) / (S_2/d_2)$; that is the F-statistic.

Comment: @jbowman I copied line below from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution)
|>> The F-distribution with d1 and d2 degrees of freedom is the distribution of
$ X={\frac {S_{1}/d_{1}}{S_{2}/d_{2}}}$

Comment: That quoted sentence is correct, but what you said before differs from it.

Comment: $X$ and the distribution of $X$ are different entities.

Comment: I think I was right in the sense that the distribution of F-statistic under null hypothesis only depends on degrees of freedom and does not depend on population statistic. What I couldn’t notice was that it is only the case if null hypothesis true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the whole point!

The distribution of most summary statistics will depend on everything about the distribution. That means you can't easily use them for testing, because you can't work out the appropriate distribution for **your** data.  Statistics researchers spent a lot of effort looking for statistics whose distribution doesn't depend on unknown parameters, in order to use them for tests.

The $F$ statistic distribution doesn't depend on the means, because the means get subtracted off: you can see that adding the same number to all the data values doesn't affect the $F$ statistic.  It doesn't depend on the true variance (if it's the same in the two groups): if you change the units that your variable is measured in, you will multiply or divide the two variances by the same amount and not change the $F$ statistic.  The statistic has the same distribution family (the $F$ distribution with the appropriate degrees of freedom) whenever you have two populations that have Normal distributions and the same variance.

Nothing is perfect, and the distribution of the $F$ statistic **does** depend on the shape of the data distribution. For example, long-tailed data distributions will make the $F$ statistic more variable than an $F$ distribution should be, and so can mess up the test when you are genuinely using it to compare two variances.